# Docker with different Container OS and Host OS

Tags: docker, operating-system, containers, virtualization

I am aware that Docker containers shares the host OS, id it possible to run two different container environments on a single host OS/machine?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. That's what containers are meant for. Go through the docs to grasp the fundamentals. I am not sure if this is the right place to ask these sort of questions. You can try it on your system & post issues here.

Comment: I disagree with what @vivekyad4v said and suggest that this question requires a nuanced answer and is an atypical example of how one would use a Docker installation on their workstation or server. Therefore one would not simply "grasp the fundamentals" of such a answer by "going through the docs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. In fact, some enterprise solutions actually take advantage of this solution. Rancher, for example, creates a platform for deploying Kubernetes environments. The underlying operating systems for the nodes are typically deployed as their own OS, RancherOS. Wherein there are two instances of the Docker daemon running. One for userland, and one for system apps. RancherOS is unique in that is runs all essential system services as containers on the host. So when you connect to a node, you can run a `system-docker ps` and see the state of all the services. However, if you run a `docker ps` you will only see your userland containers.

Here is more information on this solution: https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.2/en/system-services/adding-system-services/

As for doing so yourself, this is also possible and somewhat simple. Here is an example of someone doing so: https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2018/Feb/25/multiple-docker/

Alternatively, if you didn't want to modify your personal workstation, you can also run docker within a docker container using a project like this: https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind

Let me know if I can help you with anything else. :)

Comment: Thank you!! Can we use vagrant for building a docker/container,Please correct me if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: I have never used Vagrant but I don't see why not. All that is required to build a docker container is creating a dockerfile and running a `docker build` on it. Based on these docs: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/basics.html it looks possible to achieve your goal by using the code available in the `Dockerfiles` section of this webpage. You just ensure that both your dockerfile and vagrantfile are in the same directory and when `vagrant up --provider=docker` is run, the Dockerfile is automatically built. And then rebuilt when `vagrant reload` is also called.